# Creating a custom trust policy when creating a new IAM role using AWS-CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm trying to create a custom trust policy for an IAM role I'm creating via AWS-CDK.  Below is the JSON I'm trying to implement. Not sure if 'custom' is the right term but it's something other than new iam.ServicePrincipal class.

```json
{
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:root"
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                "Condition": {
                    "StringEquals": {
                        "sts:ExternalId": "XXXXX"
                    }
                }
            }
            ]
        }
```

I've tried doing to following in my build but it keeps failing on me with the error below.

```js
    const externalPolicyDocument = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:root"
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                "Condition": {
                    "StringEquals": {
                        "sts:ExternalId": "XXXX"
                    }
                }
            }
            ]
        }

        const jsonCustomDocument = iam.PolicyDocument.fromJson(externalPolicyDocument);
        
        new iam.Role(this, `${kinesisData.iamRole}`, {
            //assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal(`kinesis.amazonaws.com`),
            assumedBy: jsonCustomDocument,
            description: `${kinesisData.iamDescription}`,
            roleName: `${kinesisData.iamRoleName}`,
            inlinePolicies: {
                kinesisPolicy: kinesisIAMStatement,
                kmsPolicy: kinesisKMS
            }
        })
```

Below is the error I get:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Twilio-CDK-EventSink/devops/aws-cdk/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/policy-statement.js:141
            util_1.mergePrincipal(this.principal, fragment.principalJson);
                                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'principalJson' of undefined
    at AwsStarStatement.addPrincipals (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Twilio-CDK-EventSink/devops/aws-cdk/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/policy-statement.js:141:60)
    at createAssumeRolePolicy (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Twilio-CDK-EventSink/devops/aws-cdk/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/role.js:317:15)
    at new Role (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Twilio-CDK-EventSink/devops/aws-cdk/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/role.js:64:33)
    at new kinesisSinkBuild (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Twilio-CDK-EventSink/devops/aws-cdk/resources/kinesis_build.js:77:9)
    at new MainStack (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Twilio-CDK-EventSink/devops/aws-cdk/lib/aws-cdk-stack.js:18:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Twilio-CDK-EventSink/devops/aws-cdk/bin/aws-cdk.js:28:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
Subprocess exited with error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an [Account Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.AccountPrincipal.html) with conditions:

```js
assumedBy: new iam.AccountPrincipal('123456789012').withConditions({
  StringEquals: {
    'sts:ExternalId': 'XXXX',
  },
});
```